# Configure Time Machine after reinstalling Mac OS to take previous backups into account

Tags: macos, time-machine, install

I have reinstalled my Mac OS (10.9) and had to specify again my external hard drive for backups in Time Machine preferences.  Now i can enter Time Machine and see my previous backups.

However, Time Machine preferences show

```
Oldest backup: None
Latest backup: None
```

In particular, the estimated size for a new backup indicates that it will have to make a complete backup, without taking into account that most files in my home directory have not changed since the previous backup (before the Mac OS reinstallation).

Can i configure Time Machine to recognize the previous backups and to only backup modified files in my home directory?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. The command line utility can assist

```
man tmutil
```

You'll want to use the verbs **inheritbackup**, **setdestination** and/or **associatedisk** to point out the pre-existing backup you wish to adopt by the new Mac/OS.

This is covered in very nice detail on the help / manual page - pay attention to the section after this sentence:

> A concrete example of when and how you would use associatedisk:

Comment: Thank you, but so far it didn't work.  Instead of `setdestination`, i used the Time Machine pane in System Preferences and i used the verbs `inheritbackup ` and `associatedisk`, but it still does not recognize previous backups.  I will try to experiment with it later.

Comment: I also tried to use Migration Assistant as indicated [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH14293), but it didn't even find the backup disk, maybe because i have already fiddled with it...

Comment: After trying different commands with `tmutil` without visible effect, i started a backup.  The backup turned out to be about 5 times smaller than a complete backup would be, but also about 5 times larger than a normal incremental backup i would expect, and it backed up some files i didn't touch (i checked this with BackupLoupe).  As a result, Time Machine also started to show correct Oldest and Latest backup times.  This all is quite confusing.

Comment: @Alexey It sounds odd, but I bet the next few intervals are sane. Also - BackupLoupe is so good for figuring out things, but I've also had times when its monitoring affected the backups - so try turning off the loupe scanner if you have that enabled.